# Using JSR82 in Java Application

Tags: java, bluetooth

I am trying to write a Java application showcasing Bluetooth features.  On general search, I found JSR82 has been defined for the same.

I am not able to figure out exactly how to use it.  I am using standard java 1.6 and I believe for JSR82 implementation I would need J2ME running.

I need help to understand how to use the 2 java editions together.  I have never worked with the Micro Edition before.  Would appreciate any inputs.

Thanks & Regards,

Keya

Comment: if you don't want to use J2ME, JSR82 is not the JSR you are looking for.

Comment: A similar question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178856/javaj2se-and-bluetooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple try using a JSR82 implementation on your mobile device - it should work.

[This site](http://www.jsr82.com/) has some good information about it.

Here are two JSR82 implementations I know of:

- [Bluecove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/)
- [Avetana](http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/jsr82.eng.xml)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the pointer.  I will try these implementations.

Actually I am finding trouble installing J2ME on my system too.  I am working currently with Java 1.6 and when I try to install the J2ME sdk package, it complaints about the version.

I am on Linux too.

Thanks & Regards,
Keya

Comment: Avetana library fulfilled the requirement.  Didn't try the Bluecove.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://java.sun.com.

Install the jdk and the latest full version of Netbeans for your linux computer.

Use Netbeans to create a HelloWorld mobile application

Run it in the Wireless ToolKit emulator packaged into Netbeans.

That should work right out of the box.

You then need to read the JSR-118 specification to understand how a MIDlet works.

Then read the emulator documentation to figure out how to provide bluetooth data to your MIDlet.

Comment: Hey,  Thanks for the reply.  But I am looking more for writing a non-j2me based java application.  A standard one.  Hence, don't want to get in to NetBeans and other stuff.

Comment: removed j2me from question tags. jsr82 is for j2me only. j2se has a differetn way of using bluetooth.

Comment: Sorry for the tagging it with j2me.  Can you please tell me how to use bluetooth with j2se?